# Java draw two different shapes in multiple JFrames

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I have a question

I created a JComponent derived class to draw a graphic. I want a JFrame containing g1 and a second one containing g2. I only get copies of either g1 or g2 but not g1 in frame 1 and g2 in frame 2 why?

```
public class DRAWINGS_COMPONENT extends JComponent{
/**
 * 
 */
public void draw1(Graphics g1) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 60, 60);       
}
/**
 * 
 */
public void draw2(Graphics g1) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();
    g.drawOval(0, 0, 60, 60);
}
```

and the problematic class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GRAPHICS_REPRESENTATION extends JFrame {
private DRAWINGS_COMPONENT dc;
private DRAWINGS_COMPONENT dc2;

public GRAPHICS_REPRESENTATION() {
    dc=new DRAWINGS_COMPONENT();
    dc.draw1(getGraphics());
    JFrame f=new JFrame("graphic global");      
    f.add(dc);
    f.setSize(800, 800);
    f.setVisible(true); 
}

/**
 * @param x1 
 * @param y1 
 * @param g 
 * @param scene_index 
 * 
 */
public void regenerateGraphics(int x1, int y1) {
    dc2=new DRAWINGS_COMPONENT();
    dc2.draw2(getGraphics());
    JFrame f=new JFrame("graphic local");       
    f.add(dc2);     
    f.setSize(800, 800);
    f.setLocation(x1, y1);      
    f.setVisible(true); 
}
```

and the main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
GRAPHICS_REPRESENTATION g = new GRAPHICS_REPRESENTATION();
g.regenerateGraphics(50, 50);
}
```

Comment: A valid [mcve] would help us understand your question and your problem to a much greater degree.

Comment: `dc.paint(getGraphics());` is a bad idea to start with. Java (as do many languages) has a recommend coding style. While you're under no obligation to follow it, it will make it easier for you to read other peoples code and for other people to read yours

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry i typed it in a hurry i meant paintComponent.

Comment: Still a bad idea

Comment: My case is a little more complicated but for now i want dc in frame 1 with a rectangle and dc2 in frame 2 with a circle. I have here only two rectangles.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Apologize I corrected it so it gets easier to test and understand

Comment: @MadProgrammer edited to follow recommandations

Comment: It's been 2 weeks and I still need an answer, how to draw a rectangle in frame 1 and a circle in frame 2? Meanwhile i've been working on data modeling so it's not laziness from me.